# Training data algorithm not working. (Perceptron)

Tags: java, algorithm, neural-network

I am trying to write an algorithm to train perceptron but there seems to be values exceeding max value for double. I have been trying to figure out since yesterday but cannot.

The value of weights seems to be exceeding as well as the value of variable output.

The text file that is read in is of the form:
[Input variables and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XRRF.png)

```
/**
* Created by yafael on 12/3/16.
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Perceptron {

static double[] weights;
static ArrayList<Integer> inputValues;
static ArrayList<Integer> outputValues;
static int[] inpArray;
static int[] outArray;

public static int numberOfInputValues(String filePath)throws IOException
{
    Scanner valueScanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    int num = valueScanner.nextInt();
    return num;
}

public static void inputs(String filePath)throws IOException
{
    inputValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    outputValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner valueScanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
    int num = valueScanner.nextInt();

    while (valueScanner.hasNext())
    {
        String temp = valueScanner.next();
        String[] values = temp.split(",");
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
        {
            if(i+1 != values.length)
            {
                inputValues.add(Integer.parseInt(values[i]));
            }else
            {
                outputValues.add(Integer.parseInt(values[i]));
            }
        }

    }
    valueScanner.close();
}

public static void trainData(int[] inp, int[] out, int num,int epoch)
{
    weights = new double[num];
    Random r = new Random();
    int i,ep;
    int error = 0;
    /*
     * Initialize weights
     */
    for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        weights[i] = r.nextDouble();
    }

    for(ep = 1; ep<= epoch; ep++)
    {
        double totalError = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < inp.length/(num); i++)
        {
            double output = calculateOutput(inp, i, weights);
            System.out.println("Output " + (i + 1) + ": " + output);
            //System.out.println("Output: " + output);
            if(output > 0)
            {
                error = out[i] - 1;
            }else
            {
                error = out[i] - 0;
            }

            for(int temp = 0; temp < num; temp++)
            {
                double epCalc = (1000/(double)(1000+ep));
                weights[temp] += epCalc*error*inp[((i*weights.length)+temp)];
                //System.out.println("Epoch calculation: " + epCalc);
                //System.out.println("Output: " + output);
                //System.out.println("error: " + error);
                //System.out.println("input " + ((i*weights.length)+temp) + ": " + inp[(i*weights.length)+temp]);
            }
            totalError += (error*error);
        }
        //System.out.println("Total Error: " + totalError);

        if(totalError == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("In total error");
            for(int temp = 0; temp < num; temp++)
            {
                System.out.println("Weight " +(temp)+ ": " + weights[temp]);
            }

            double x = 0.0;
            for(i = 0; i < inp.length/(num); i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < weights.length; j++)
                {
                    x = inp[((i*num) + j)] * weights[j];
                }
                System.out.println("Output " + (i+1) + ": " + x);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    if(ep >= 10000)
    {
        System.out.println("Solution not found");
    }
}

public static double calculateOutput(int[] input, int start, double[] weights)
{
    start = start * weights.length;
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println("input[" + (start + i) + "]: " + input[(start+i)]);
        //System.out.println("weights[i]" + weights[i]);
        sum += (double)input[(start + i)] * weights[i];
    }
    return sum - 1.0 ;
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //Read the file path from the user
    String fileName;
    System.out.println("Please enter file path for Execution: ");
    fileName = obj.readLine();

    int numInputValues = numberOfInputValues(fileName);

    //Call the function to store values in the ArrayList<>
    inputs(fileName);
    inpArray = inputValues.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    outArray = outputValues.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();

    trainData(inpArray, outArray, numInputValues, 10000);
}
}
```

Comment: are you getting overflow error? what exact problem you are facing and in which segment of your program is causing you problem?

Comment: @WasiAhmad thanks for your comment. The problem is, my values of weights should stay within the range of 0.0 - 1.0. But they are exponentially increasing. After a few iterations, the method calculateOutput returns NaN

Comment: Can you share your full code so that i can run and check? By the way, what is the point of deducting `0 from out[i]` inside else block. Moreover, you can write `1000.0 / (1000.0 + ep)` instead of `(1000/(double)(1000+ep))`.

Comment: I am doing that just so that it's easy to read and comprehend. Once I get the code working, I am going to clean it up. Thanks again for the input. Also, I have updated the code for your reference

Comment: What is `num` in `trainData` function? Is it batch size or the input size? If it is input size, then why you are running a for loop from `0 to inp.length/num`? Besides, i can see why the weight values are exploding!! because you are updating weight values by multiplying `epCalc, output, error and inp[((i*weights.length)+temp)]` which will be a large value. In neural network, we usually have a learning parameter, we need to take gradients and update weights. the way you are updating weights is not appropriate. i believe your understanding about updating neural network model parameters is wrong!

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the update!

Comment: I have given an example which you might get helpful. You have few things to improve. If you find my example helpful, you can accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code is problematic, so i am giving you a simple example but i am sure you will get help from this code to resolve your problem.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Perceptron {
    double[] weights;
    double threshold;
    public void Train(double[][] inputs, int[] outputs, double threshold, double lrate, int epoch) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
        int n = inputs[0].length;
        int p = outputs.length;
        weights = new double[n];
        Random r = new Random();

        //initialize weights
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            weights[i] = r.nextDouble();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<epoch;i++) {
            int totalError = 0;
            for(int j =0;j<p;j++) {
                int output = Output(inputs[j]);
                int error = outputs[j] - output;

                totalError +=error;

                for(int k=0;k<n;k++) {
                    double delta = lrate * inputs[j][k] * error;
                    weights[k] += delta;
                }
            }
            if(totalError == 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    public int Output(double[] input) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            sum += weights[i]*input[i];
        }

        if(sum>threshold)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Perceptron p = new Perceptron();
        double inputs[][] = {{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}};
        int outputs[] = {0,0,0,1};

        p.Train(inputs, outputs, 0.2, 0.1, 200);
        System.out.println(p.Output(new double[]{0,0})); // prints 0
        System.out.println(p.Output(new double[]{1,0})); // prints 0
        System.out.println(p.Output(new double[]{0,1})); // prints 0
        System.out.println(p.Output(new double[]{1,1})); // prints 1
    }
}
```